# Fill array with numpy (Python) that includes one colum with datetime values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, datetime-format

Daer Folks,

I like to create a 2D Array, one colum with datetime values.
So far, I manged to get this:

```
import numpy as np
desc = np.dtype([('date', np.datetime64), ('float', np.float64)])
meanDN = np.empty([len(onlyfiles), 2], dtype = desc)
```

Which doesn't work when:

```
print(meanDN)
```

Why?

Comment: `desc = np.dtype([('date', 'datetime64[s]'), ('float', np.float64)])` works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot populate numpy datetime64 arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27469031/cannot-populate-numpy-datetime64-arrays)