# Create Array of Dates in Numba?

Tags: python, numba

I would like to create an array of dates in a Numba function, running in nopython mode.

I can't see a date type, so I am trying NPDatetime.

My attempted code is:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np


@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def xxx():
    return np.empty(10, dtype=nb.types.NPDatetime('D'))


print(xxx())
```

However, the code returns this error:

```
Unknown attribute 'NPDatetime' of type Module(<module 'numba.types' from '/home/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/types/__init__.py'>)
```

My numba version is 0.39.0

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:**
I have to correct myself, both `numpy.empty()` and `datetime64` are supported by numba:

> Numba supports the following Numpy scalar types: [...] Datetimes and timestamps: of any unit [...]
>   
> <sub>Source: [Section 2.7.1](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.39.0/reference/numpysupported.html#scalar-types)</sub>

> `numpy.empty()` (only the 2 first arguments)
>   
> <sub>Source: [Section 2.7.3.3](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.39.0/reference/numpysupported.html#other-functions)</sub>

**No idea what causes your problem.**

---

You have specified the `dtype` argument incorrectly. Numpy doesn't use the numba classes for it. Here is how you could specify `dtype` correctly: (Read more [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27469031/cannot-populate-numpy-datetime64-arrays))

```
dtype="datetime64[D]"
```

But even if you specified the argument that way, it would not work. The `nopython` argument to `@nb.jit()` doesn't natively support that type. Here is the corrected code: (Read more [here](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.39.0/glossary.html#term-nopython-mode))

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.jit
def xxx():
  return np.empty(10, dtype="datetime64[D]")

print(xxx())
```

But consider giving numba a type hint:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.jit(nb.types.NPDatetime('D')()) # returns datatime, no arguments
def xxx():
  return np.empty(10, dtype="datetime64[D]")

print(xxx())
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is it currently impossible to use a date type in nopython mode? At present, I am getting around it by using integers instead.

Answer (score 2):

I have never used numba or numpy before so it took a little bit of research, but this should work.

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
from numba import *

def xxx():
    return np.empty(10, dtype=np.dtype(np.datetime64('2014')))

jitcompute = nb.jit(nopython=True)(xxx)
print(xxx())
```

let me know if this works!

## Edit:

> as stated in the comments my code was executed without the just in time decorator implemented, with future research it seems like there is a bug where dtype cant be used inside a JIT decorated function
> https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/3066
>
> > I have spent 4-5 hours on this problem now and i cannot find a way around it, you can parse the arrays created through the xxx function, but you are not able to use empty() or zeros() inside the decorated function

Comment: Thanks @asynts stupid mistake by me, will take a look